# to not start parsing unless deep enough

Tags: scrapy

I have a website whichi architecture is as follows :
many domains and each domain has this

```
Global link<br>
special link1
special link1
special link1
special link1
```

Because there are too many domains , I have just set the depth=2 , but I don't want scrapy to start xpath unless the depth is 2 
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you show more of your spider code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spidermiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.depth) limit depth by utilizing request.meta['depth'], see its code [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/depth.py), use that as well to:

```
def myparse(self, response):
    if response.meta['depth'] == 2:
        ...
```